# Find the smallest value of a table row using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Ok currently I'm using this code to find it but I need to filter out null fields so that all my cells that are blank don't turn red.

```
$('tr').each(function highlight() {
    var $td = $(this).children('td');

    // find all the values
    var vals = $td.map(function () {
            return +$(this).text();
        }).filter(function (val) {
            return val !== null
        });
}).get();

// then find their minimum
var min = Math.min.apply(Math, vals);

// tag any cell matching the min value
$td.filter(function highlight() {
    return +$(this).text() === min;
}).addClass('alert alert-danger');
});
```

So how do I filter out the null values?

Comment: WHat do we have in tr's , Numbers or string ??

Comment: Only numbers in the table

Comment: FYI, the `.filter()` you're using inside the `.each()` callback is jQuery's filter which deviates from the standard. The `val` parameter is actually the index number for some odd reason. You want the second parameter, though its value will never be `null` since you converted the values to numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `$('#asd').text()` evaluates to ""

then `+$('#asd').text()` will evaluate to `0`

---

To find minimum in whole table

http://jsfiddle.net/6DgAW/

```
var vals = $('tr td').map(function () {
    return isNaN(parseInt($(this).text(), 10)) ? parseInt($(this).text(), 10) :  null;
}).get();

// then find their minimum
var min = Math.min.apply(Math, vals);

// tag any cell matching the min value
$('tr td').filter(function () {
    return parseInt($(this).text(), 10) === min;
}).addClass('alert alert-danger');
```

---

To find minimum in each row

http://jsfiddle.net/DggUN/18/

```
$('tr').each(function(){
    var vals = $('td,th',this).map(function () {
        return parseInt($(this).text(), 10) ? parseInt($(this).text(), 10) :  null;
    }).get();
    // then find their minimum
    var min = Math.min.apply(Math, vals);

    // tag any cell matching the min value
    $('td,th', this).filter(function () {
        return parseInt($(this).text(), 10) === min;
    }).addClass('alert alert-danger');
});
```

Comment: Can you first recheck your paranthesis in your code and post again, right now `vals` and `$td` is inside scope of the closure for `$.each`.

Comment: other than that, you can return null from `map` to filter items. To filter only numbers for comparison use `parseInt` and check if its `NaN`. My current code will fail for `0`

Comment: You want minimum in each row? I thought you want minimum of whole table, sorry

Comment: Ah no I need it for each row :)

Comment: Hmm I'm having a problem with it avoiding decimals. I have a row that has 0.3, 0.5, and 1. And it thinks 1 is the smallest. How can I avoid this?

Comment: use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested this code

```
   var min=0; 
   $("tr").each(function(e){
     var tr = $(this);
     var valuses =$(this).find(".YourClassNameForTheParticularfield").html(); 
     if(!isNaN(Number(Values))) //NullChecking
     {
        if(min>Number(mark));
          {
            min = mark;
          }
      }
   });
```

isNaN checks whether it is not a number which includes null or text , Using isNaN may solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

```
var rows = $("tr");
var minValArray = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = rows[i];
    var elements = $(row).find("td");
    var min = 9999999999; // make this larger than other numbers in your table
    for(var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
        if(!isNaN(parseInt($(elements[j]).text())) && parseInt($(elements[j]).text()) < min)
             min = parseInt($(elements[j]));
    }
    minValArray.push(min);
}
```

This should give minimum of all the rows in an array.