# jQuery - Find smallest value in table row and style it

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

First of all - I'm very new to jQuery/JS

I have a website which displays sports results. There are 6 tournaments each year, but only the 4 best results are used for the ranking.

I have a table on the website which is filled via jQuery from google spreadsheets (via sheetrock).

The table looks like this:

```js
$('tr').each(function() {
  var vals = $('td:nth-child(n+3):nth-last-child(n+2)', this).map(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).text()) ? parseInt($(this).text()) : null;
  }).get();
  var min = Math.min.apply(Math, vals);

  $('td:nth-child(n+3):nth-last-child(n+2)', this).filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).text()) === min;
  }).css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Rang</th>
      <th>Team</th>
      <th>KC</th>
      <th>ZB</th>
      <th>BVO</th>
      <th>BW</th>
      <th>MC</th>
      <th>BB</th>
      <th>TOTAL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Eckl/Lak</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>400</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Pointner/Wimmer J.</td>
      <td>70</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>70</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>220</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Grießler/Svetanic</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>62</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>198</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

All I want to do now is to let jQuery check each row of the table if there are more than 4 results. If there are more than 4 I'd like to line-through the smallest value.

I use this to identify the rows with more than 4 results:

```js
$('table tr').filter(function() {
      return $(this).children('td:empty').length < 2;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To style the cells I use this:

```js
$('tr').each(function() {
  var vals = $('td:nth-child(n+3):nth-last-child(n+2)', this).map(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).text()) ? parseInt($(this).text()) : null;
  }).get();
  var min = Math.min.apply(Math, vals);

  $('td:nth-child(n+3):nth-last-child(n+2)', this).filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).text()) === min;
  }).css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But there are a few things that obviously aren't working.

Currently, it identifies all the minimum values for each row. Hence, if there are multiple minimum values it also styles every min-value and not only one of them.

Also I don't know how to incorporate this in an if-statement.

I was really hoping that somebody could help me out here.

Comment: what would you rather have it do? style only the first one? and update your snippet add a reference to jquery cdn.

Comment: check your jquery cdn file properly linked...

Comment: @jidexl21 exactly - I only want 1 to be styled, I really don't care if it is the first, middle, last, whatever occurrence - as long as it's only 1

Answer (score 0):

**To find minimum in whole table**

```
var vals = $('tr td').map(function () {
    return isNaN(parseInt($(this).text(), 10)) ? parseInt($(this).text(), 10) :  null;
}).get();

// then find their minimum
var min = Math.min.apply(Math, vals);

// tag any cell matching the min value
$('tr td').filter(function () {
    return parseInt($(this).text(), 10) === min;
}).addClass('alert alert-danger');
```

**To find minimum in each row**

```
$('tr').each(function(){
    var vals = $('td,th',this).map(function () {
        return parseInt($(this).text(), 10) ? parseInt($(this).text(), 10) :  null;
    }).get();
    // then find their minimum
    var min = Math.min.apply(Math, vals);

    // tag any cell matching the min value
    $('td,th', this).filter(function () {
        return parseInt($(this).text(), 10) === min;
    }).addClass('alert alert-danger');
});
```

you should check this out- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22470186/1665370

Comment: Thanks - Actually that's where I got my "find minimum" function from